# I have an error in Kotlin caused by a mutableState

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The error is produced when I called the element, it seems that the first argument is of a different type than expected, but I don't understand why, I'm confused, by the way I'm learning jetpack-compose

My code

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            QuizAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val puntuacion by remember {
                        mutableStateOf(0)
                    }
                    QuizElement(puntuacion, vidas = 3)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun QuizElement(puntuacion: MutableState<Int>, vidas: Int) {
    // Una variable local para guardar la opción seleccionada por el usuario
    var opcion by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    // Una variable local para guardar la respuesta correcta
    val respuesta = "A"
    // Una variable local para obtener el contexto de la actividad
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Column {
        // Un texto que muestra la pregunta
        Text(text = "¿Cuál es la capital de Colombia?")
        // Un row que contiene dos botones con las opciones A y B
        Row {
            Button(onClick = { opcion = "A" }) {
                Text(text = "A) Bogotá")
            }
            Button(onClick = { opcion = "B" }) {
                Text(text = "B) Medellín")
            }
        }
        // Un row que contiene dos botones con las opciones C y D
        Row {
            Button(onClick = { opcion = "C" }) {
                Text(text = "C) Cali")
            }
            Button(onClick = { opcion = "D" }) {
                Text(text = "D) Cartagena")
            }
        }
        // Un botón que envía la respuesta y actualiza la puntuación si es correcta
        Button(onClick = {
            if (opcion == respuesta) {
                // Incrementar la puntuación en uno
                puntuacion.value++
                // Mostrar un mensaje de felicitación
                Toast.makeText(context, "¡Respuesta correcta!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                // Mostrar un mensaje de error
                Toast.makeText(context, "Respuesta incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = "Enviar")
        }
        // Un texto que muestra la puntuación actual
        Text(text = "Puntuación: ${puntuacion.value}")
    }
}
```

i have no idea about this error 'Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but MutableState was expected' i tried to update Kotlin but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a `delegated` mutable state of an Integer in this line of code:

```kotlin
val puntuacion by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
```

So the result is a `puntuacion` of a `Integer` type, not `MutableState<Int>`, that's because the `by` is a delegate, what does a delegate mean? It is a shortcut that saves you from calling `puntuacion.value` every time, so you just use `by` instead of `=` so you can use the Integer directly. Let me give you another example:

```
val string1 by remember { mutableStateOf("somerandomstring") } <--- this is a string

val string2 = remember { mutableStateOf("somerandomstring") } <--- this is a mutable state of a string

//When you want to get string1's value
println(string1) <--- you can use it directly

//When you want to get string2's value, you need to use .value
println(string2.value) <--- this is without using 'by' delegate
```

You should always check your variable's type when you create them. You can check the type of your variable by hovering with your mouse cursor over the variable's name. `QuizElement` is expecting a mutable state of an Integer, but you're passing an Integer, that's why the Kotlin compiler got confused.

**NOTE**: It is better to use the new `mutableIntStateOf(yourintegerhere)` instead of `mutableStateOf(yourintegerhere)` when you are creating mutable states of integers, that's because they're better for memory and faster.

There are also `mutableFloatStateOf`, `mutableDoubleStateOf`...etc

**NOTE 2**: Your `QuizElement` should receive an Integer directly in its parameter, don't pass mutable states around, you should pass their values instead, otherwise you'll run into Non-recomposition problems quite often (where changing values wouldn't trigger recomposition), unless you know what you're doing.